# Sunspot solr + Rails + timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, timezone, sunspot

In our rails application we are getting time zone from users.

select * from questions where created_at + interval '6 hour' between '2014-03-21' and '2014-03-22'

while selection questions from table adding timezone offset to get questions created in some interval.

is it possible to do the same using sunspot solr?

For example,

Question.search do 
   with(:created_at, "2014-03-24T00:00:00Z".."2014-03-24T23:59:59Z") this should added with the offset
end

Please help us to achieve this or tell me is it possible with sunspot solr or not.

Thanks,
Nandhini

Comment: Asking the same question two times its not really going to make much of a difference Nandhini. Instead, i'd suggest you make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic syntax, not 100% sure about date formats

```
Question.search do
    with(:created_at).greater_than("2014-03-24T00:00:00Z".to_datetime)
    with(:created_at).less_than("2014-03-24T23:59:59Z".to_datetime)
    ...
```